# Adding hidden value of a column in SQL Server using C# in combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

in SQL Server I have a table that have `id`,`office`, `transpo` and `allowance` columns. Now my code goes like this.

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC; Initial Catalog=DATABASE; Integrated Security=True"))
            {
conn.Open();
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select * from branch order by office asc", conn);
SqlDataReader reader;
reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("OFFICE", typeof(string));
dt.Load(reader);
comboboxDestination.ValueMember = "ID";
comboboxDestination.DisplayMember = "OFFICE";
comboboxDestination.DataSource = dt;
conn.Close();
            }
```

Now it displays ok, I can transfer what's in the combobox to the other form like I use to do.

```
 string destination;
 destination = comboboxDestination.Text.ToString();
```

My question is, in my table, I also have `transpo` and `allowance` column. How can I transfer the appropriate value of that in a variable whenever what is picked in the displayed combobox which is the `office` column?

Comment: Try `SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get values corresponding to combo box selection please go through below code:

1.Make data table accessible outside the function so define it with global aspect.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

2. Fill data table using your function.

   ```
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC; Initial Catalog=DATABASE; Integrated Security=True"))
   {
       conn.Open();
       SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select * from branch order by office asc", conn);
       SqlDataReader reader = sc.ExecuteReader();
       dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("OFFICE", typeof(string));
       dt.Load(reader);
       comboboxDestination.ValueMember = "ID";
       comboboxDestination.DisplayMember = "OFFICE";
       comboboxDestination.DataSource = dt;
       conn.Close();
   }
   ```
3. Getting combo box value on button click or combo box selection change

   ```
   private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string destination="";
       string transpo="";
       string allowance="";
       destination = comboboxDestination.Text.ToString();

      //Function to get values regarding selected combo box value.
      foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
          if(row["OFFICE"].ToString().ToUpper() == destination.ToUpper())
          {
              transpo=row["Transpo"].ToString();
              allowance=row["Allowance"].ToString();
              break;
          }
      }
      Console.Write("Transpo = "+ transpo);
      Console.Write("Allowance= "+ allowance);
   }
   ```

Comment: Mark it as answered if you find it working so it will help others too.... and please feel free to ping me if you have any query or problem.

Comment: I've used your method and it worked base on what I actually need. Thank you!